# How to find and replace list in dict by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have a dict like

```
{"First": [[val1, 20], [val2, 20]]}
```

but i need rewrite this dict when i found new data for each value, for example i have new data for value 1 and key "First", and how can i update dict to get new like this:

```
{"First": [[val1, **100**], [val2, 20]]}
```

Comment: Is that dict in a string? or have you just put quotes around it? Makes a difference

Comment: sorry, just printed via json
that dict is not a string

Comment: Why is the 100 inside a double asterisk?

Comment: do you want this `d['First'][0][1] = 100` ?

Comment: @DishinHGoyani i need to find val1 from all values of "First" and replace second element of this list

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to insert the value `new = [val1, 100]` for key 'First'

```py
new = [val1, 100]
for i,row in enumerate(d['First']):
    if row[0] == val1:
        d['First'][i] = new
        break
```

If you have several keys, you can use an if condition there also.

Answer (score 2):

If `val1`and `val2` need to be accessed externally and have no value themselves, why can you not use a `dict` or `dicts`?

```
d = {} # create dict of dicts
d['First'] = {}
d['First'] = {'val1':20, 'val2':20}
```

Then, to change `val1`, you just have to do:

```
d['First']['val1']=100
```

Comment: Yes, using a dict of dicts would make it a lot neater and easy :)